# Infinite sets closed under some binary operation, their subsets and question of cardinality

Tags: set-theory

Can it be that there exists some infinite set $S$ and some binary operation $b: S \times S \to S$ such that cardinality of subsets of $S$ which are closed under $b$ is greater than the cardinality of $S$?

*Edit*:  Since edit was requested, I would like to mention that I wanted $b$ to include both of the variables in its definition and that it is almost-everywhere non-constant (in other words, it is possibly constant only on finite number of pairs) so that binary operations such as $b(s_1,s_2)=s_1$ and $b(s_1,s_2)=s_*$ are not allowed.

Comment: What about the operation $b(s_1, s_2)=s_1$?  Then all subsets are closed under the operation, yes?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Could you edit your post to include some of your thoughts? Why do you think it could be true?

Comment: I think this question would be a bit more interesting under stricter conditions on $b$, i.e., $S$ is an abelian group under $b$.

Comment: @DonThousand I agree that your variant of the question is more interesting - I've addressed it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without restrictions on the binary operation, this is not difficult.

For instance, all subsets of $S$ are closed under  $$b_1:S\times S\to S$$  $$(s_1,s_2)\mapsto s_1$$

Or, if $s_*\in S$ is some element in $S$, we could consider the constant operation $$b_2:S\times S\to S$$  $$(s_1,s_2)\mapsto s_*$$

under which every subset which contains $s_*$ is closed.

If you had some restrictions on the nature of the binary operation, please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can even find abelian groups with this property.

For example, consider the free abelian group on a countably infinite set of  generators. Another name for this group is $\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$, the group of all infinite integer sequences with all but finitely many terms equal to $0$, with pointwise addition.

This group is countably infinite, but it has uncountably many subgroups. For example, for any set $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, the set $G_S = \{(n_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\mid n_i = 0 \text{ for all }i\in S\}$, consisting of all integer sequences which are $0$ at all coordinates in $S$, is a subgroup, and $G_S\neq G_T$ when $S\neq T$.